# racket can not find libserialport-0.dll

Tags: racket

I try to use libserialport in DrRacket.
The libserialport is https://docs.racket-lang.org/libserialport/index.html .
I install the libserialport package source by the DrRacket "file->package manager".
After installation, when I use (require libserialport) in DrRacket, there's a error 
**ffi-lib: couldn't open "libserialport-0.dll"**
How to fix it?  thanks

Comment: Have you installed [the library](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport)? The racket page you linked  to writes it needs to be installed externally.

Comment: I installed the racket libserial through the DrRacket->file->package_manager. Maybe I need to install the git://sigrok.org/libserialport externally? I tried to compile the libserialport source to libserialport-0.dll but don't know how. The README in the libserialport source  only tells a way to install the source in msys2.

Comment: @Mars What OS do you have?

Comment: @soegaard windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The installation from DrRacket does not actually install the library itself, only the racket bindings to a library that needs to be installed prior to use. The error message you see is because it doesn't find the library since it's not yet installed.

In the documentation is clearly states:

> It (the library) must be installed externally to this Racket module,
>   preferrably via the system package manager.

To install the library go to the [Downloads section](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads#Binaries_and_distribution_packages) on [libserialport's project page](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport) and download and install the one matching your operating system and architecture. When installed the racket module should work.

Comment: Thank you very much. I use win10 and install the libserialport in msys2 and get the libserialport-0.dll in "C:\msys64\mingw32\bin". I also set this path into windows system path. But still DrRacket can not open the libserialport-0.dll file.

Comment: @Mars I don't have Windows on any of my machines so I'm afraid I can't help you further. Perhaps someone else can update my answer on where to put the dll or set environment variables so that it finds it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this done now.
For windows(32bit or 64bit),

1. Install [libserialport](http://sigrok.org/wiki/Libserialport) in msys2-MinGW-32-bit environment. Then the file libserialport-0.dll is done.
2. Add the path of libserialport-0.dll file into the windows system PATH.
3. Install Racket(i386-win32) & the [libserial binding](https://docs.racket-lang.org/libserialport/index.html). Then (require libserialport) will work.

Notice that the Racket(x86_64) can not load the libserialport-0.dll successfully.

Thanks to @Sylwester .